# Obtaining file path in QGIS Training Manual

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qgis-3

> **6.2.5 Try Yourself: Convert Layers’ CRS**
>
> ...
>
> *8. Repeat this process for each layer, creating a new layer in
> the vector_analysis.gpkg GeoPackage file with _34S appended to the
> original name and removing each of the old layers from the project.*

link: https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/training_manual/vector_analysis/basic_analysis.html

I appear to have successfully added `roads_34S` to the `vector_analysis.gpkg` file:
[image]

My goal now is to repeat the process with restaurants, schools and buildings. I open the Save Vector Layer as … dialog and enter the Layer name and find the correct CRS. Now I want to use the ellipse button by file name to find the file path:
[image]

I search for `vector_analysis.gpkg` to obtain the file path. When adding the roads layer, I put the new package into a folder, `myExerciseData`, reserved for files that I create. I click the button and get the following, showing that the filenames are inactive.
[image]

Since the file names are inactive, I cannot open a file, which seems to mean that I cannot save the restaurants_34S layer with the new CRS to the file `vector_analysis.gpkg`. What have I missed? Do I have to enter the file path manually?

I try entering `vector_analysis.gpkg`. I click on Save. I get this dialog:
[image]

What has gone wrong here?

The following was added after Ben W's response.

I filled the boxes in the order in which they appear, as in the following image. The filenames remained inactive as above in the `Save Layer as...` dialog.

[image]

When I selected OK, I got a new dialog box:

[image]

Does this offer a clue? Are there any OS X users on this forum?

Comment: All I can suggest is try setting your file path to vector_analysis.gpkg ***before*** changing the layer name and CRS. I am not a Mac user so I don't know of any posible Mac-specific issues, but I just tested this in Windows and I had no problems replicating the exercise from the training manual.

Comment: I tried @Ben W's suggestion and extended the question.